# VHDL assign a number to signal's name

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I am about to use random numbers to choose a signal but can't assign the number to that signal's name.

In this code, I have three input ports which their name are:
A1B, A2B, A3B, A4B

now I want to use them randomly by a rand function between 1 to 4.

```
rand = 4, then input A4B selected.
rand = 2, then input A2B selected.
rand = 3, then input A3B selected.
```

This is not an array that I use simple ().

```
for (i=1; i<5; i++)
   A[i]B = 1 + i;
```

something like this.

Comment: Use a `switch()` statement?

Comment: Or use `if...elsif...elsif...else...end if;`?

Comment: Please learn how to format questions here.

Comment: Thank you, next time ;)

Comment: Objects cannot be indirectly addressed. Use a proper array for your purpose. Your example code isn't formatted as VHDL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and readable approach would be using `switch` cases.

If you don't want have `switch` or `if-else`.

Have a array of pointer pointing to those variables.

**Example:**

```
int A1B,A2B,A3B,A4B;
int *ptr[] = {&A1B, &A2B, &A3B, &A4B};

for (i=1; i<5; i++)
   *ptr[i-1] = 1 + i;
```

> Note: you need to dereference `ptr[i]` to access the value and
>   `*ptr[1]` will give you `A2B`.

---

You don't need to have array of pointers if you can have array of ports directly.

**example:**

```
int AxB[100];
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need this in VHDL :)

Comment: @VHDLVerificationgeek I'm not familiar with VHDL. Since this question is tagged as `C` I have answered it in `C`.